# Shortest curve between two points using finite differences

Tags: proof-verification, optimization, finite-differences

> Use the method of finite differences to find the shortest plane curve connecting two points $A $ and $B $

Typically, I would just use the Euler equation to do this type of problem, but using finite differences sounded intriguing.

If we let  $$J [y] = \int_a^b \sqrt {1+y'^2}dx = \int_a^b \sqrt {dx^2+dy^2} $$

And assume that the point $A$ is at $(a,\alpha)$ and $B $ is at $(b, \beta)$.

We can separate the interval from $(a, \alpha)$ to $ (b,\beta)$ into $n+1$ polygonal lines.

Let $$a =  x_0 < x_1 < x_2 <... < x_n < x_{n+1}  = b \space \text { and } y_k = y (x_k) $$

Then
$$L(y_1,y_2,...,y_n) =  \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \sqrt{h^2+(y_{i}-y_{i-1})^2} $$
Where $h = x_{i}-x_{i-1} $ (here we have assumed the points are evenly space w.r.t. $x $)

It is clear that for large $n $,

$L(y_1,...,y_n) \approx J[y] $,
and the equality becomes exact as $n \to \infty $.

We are trying to minimize, so it seems to me that we must first establish a critical point by taking the gradient of $L $ and setting it to $\vec{0}$. This would amount to taking the partial derivative with respect to each $y_i $ and setting them all equal to $0$

There are two terms that depend on each $y_i $. Generally speaking,

$$\frac {\partial L}{\partial y_i} =  \frac {(y_i-y_{i-1})}{\sqrt {h^2+(y_i-y_{i-1})^2}} +  \frac {(y_{i}-y_{i+1})}{\sqrt {h^2+(y_{i}-y_{i+1})^2}} =  0$$

For algebraic purposes, let $p = y_i-y_{i-1} $ and $q = y_i-y_{i+1}$

$$\frac {p}{\sqrt {h^2+p^2}}=- \frac {q}{\sqrt {h^2+q^2}} $$

$$p^2 (h^2+q^2) = q^2 (h^2+p^2) $$

$$p^2 h^2 = q^2 h^2$$

$$q = p \implies y_{i+1} - y_i = y_i - y_{i-1} $$
So that $$\frac {y_{i+1}+y_{i-1}}2 = 
y_i $$
Thus for all $1 \le i \le n$, the point $y_i $ is the average of its neighboring points. This is consistent with lines, but is only a necessary, not sufficient, condition to be a line. If we take $n \to \infty $, then $y_{i}-y_{i-1} $ become infinitesimally close to each other. That is to say, *every* point, $y $, on the curve is the average of any two points equally spaced from $y $

This implies that $y(x) $ is a line with slope $\frac {\beta-\alpha}{b-a} $

It gave the desired concluion, but is this approach correct?

Comment: Straight line... no?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: I don't understand your comment. Straight line... yes?

Comment: The argument looks fine to me except the part that begins "If we take $n\to\infty$". Instead let $k=y_1-y_0$ and use the averaging property to show that $y_2=y_0+2k,y_3=y_0+3k,\dots,y_n=nk$.

Comment: @Rahul: That's a nice representation, but I still feel that doesn't *prove* it's a line, it just carries that property of a line. For example, we could have a function which is periodic (with period $h $) about the line connecting $A $ to $B $, and this would satisfy the relation of averages still.

Comment: Well, after this you can take the limit as $n\to\infty$. The argument you have instead after the limit is not very clear to me.

Comment: @Rahul: ah, okay. Yes, I agree then. Personally, I don't see much difference between the arguments except that yours builds a line from the starting point and mine builds it from some arbitrary point between the start and end points. My argument was essentially saying that as $n \to \infty $, $y(x) = \frac{y(x+k) + y(x-k)}{2} $ for any $k$ and any $a \le x \le b $, but I do agree, yours is probably better explained.